# To split the testMethod() into several testMethods() in Robotium - Android JUnit test case

Tags: java, android, junit, robotium

I have been able to automate the entire flow of my application. I am having a single testMethod() that is handling the automation of the flow. I want to split this single method into several other methods to improve readability of my code. However, I have a concern here, if i split my test method into other methods, Firstly, the order of execution has to be taken care and more importantly, my Activity dies once one test runs successfully and closing the activity making the following test to fail.

How can i go about this? Is there any way i can split my testMethod into several testMethods() without the activity getting closed?

Including my current testMethod()

```
public void testApp() throws BiffException, IOException {

    Excel rd= new Excel();
    rd.read();

    user = rd.getUser();
    pass = rd.getPass();
    bp = rd.getBill();
    rdc = rd.getRdc();
    pr = rd.getPr();

    // Login to the application
    solo.enterText(0,user); // Enter user name
    solo.sleep(1000); 
    solo.enterText(1,"xxx"); //some random password
    solo.sleep(1000);
    solo.clickOnButton(1); // Try Login! (bad login)
    solo.sleep(5000);
    solo.clickOnButton(0);
    solo.sleep(2500);
    solo.enterText(1,pass); // Enter Password (authentic password)
    solo.sleep(2500);
    solo.clickOnButton(1); // Try Login! (Valid login)
    solo.sleep(10000);

    // MFA
    solo.clickOnButton(0); // choose Text Me (xxx-xxx-3576)
    solo.sleep(20000);

    //Account Summary
    solo.clickOnButton(0);
    solo.sleep(15000);

    //Account History
    if(solo.searchText(ch)){
        solo.clickOnText(ch);
        solo.sleep(10000);
    }
    else if (solo.searchText(sv)){
        solo.clickOnText(sv);
        solo.sleep(10000);
    }
    else{
        solo.clickInList(1);
    }

    //Transfers
    solo.clickOnMenuItem("Transfers");
    solo.sleep(10000);
    solo.clickOnText("From"); //choose 'From' account
    solo.sleep(5000);
    solo.clickInList(1); //click on first available account
    solo.sleep(5000);
    solo.clickOnText("To");   //choose 'To' account
    solo.sleep(5000);
    solo.clickInList(2);    //click on second available account
    solo.sleep(5000);
    solo.clickOnText("Amount"); //Amount to transfer
    solo.sleep(10000);
    solo.typeText(0,"10.00");  //enter amount for over limit transfer
    solo.sleep(5000);
    solo.clickOnButton("Transfer");
    solo.sleep(10000);
    solo.clickOnButton(0);
    solo.sleep(5000);

    //Bill Pay
    if(bp.equalsIgnoreCase(flag)){
        solo.clickOnMenuItem("Bills");
        solo.sleep(10000);
    }

    //RDC
    if (rdc.equalsIgnoreCase(flag)) {
        solo.clickOnMenuItem("Deposits");
        solo.sleep(10000);
        //solo.scrollUp();
        //solo.sleep(10000);
    }

    //PR
    if(pr.equalsIgnoreCase(flag)){
        solo.clickOnMenuItem("Rewards");
        solo.sleep(1000);
    }

    //More
    solo.clickOnMenuItem("More");
    solo.sleep(10000);

    //Call
    solo.clickOnButton(0);
    solo.sleep(10000);
    solo.clickOnButton(0); //cancel
    solo.sleep(10000);

    //Logout
    solo.clickOnImage(0); //click on Logout
    solo.sleep(5000);
    solo.clickOnButton(1); //to cancel the logout
    solo.sleep(5000);
    solo.clickOnImage(0); //click on Logout
    solo.sleep(10000);
    solo.clickOnButton(0); //Yes
    solo.sleep(10000);
}
```

Anticipate your help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
public void testApp() throws BiffException, IOException {
login();
...
logout();
}

private void login(){
// Login to the application
    solo.enterText(0,user); // Enter user name
    solo.sleep(1000); 
    solo.enterText(1,"xxx"); //some random password
    solo.sleep(1000);
    solo.clickOnButton(1); // Try Login! (bad login)
    solo.sleep(5000);
    solo.clickOnButton(0);
    solo.sleep(2500);
    solo.enterText(1,pass); // Enter Password (authentic password)
    solo.sleep(2500);
    solo.clickOnButton(1); // Try Login! (Valid login)
    solo.sleep(10000);
}

private void logout(){
    solo.clickOnImage(0); //click on Logout
    solo.sleep(5000);
    solo.clickOnButton(1); //to cancel the logout
    solo.sleep(5000);
    solo.clickOnImage(0); //click on Logout
    solo.sleep(10000);
    solo.clickOnButton(0); //Yes
    solo.sleep(10000);
}
```

So all methods starting with test (for example testMethod1, testApp, etc) during test will be called and they called other submethods.

Anyway is not possible to recover a previous state of the app.

The other solution is that you write tests with precondition: for example all that tests requires application is logged in.

Answer (score 0):

With JUnit3 every method which have the "test" prefix in the method name tell to the TestRunner that it is test.

If you want to split your `testApp` method you can, but the other methods don't have to have the "test" prefix in their names.